# Why can’t I see any change in my PHP project that runs on WampServer after I changed many things in resources?

Tags: php, wamp, localserver

I could not receive any change effect after all changes i had on the js in my php template in the wamp local server but after shutdown or maybe restart.
i restarted wampserver services or stop and run again many times but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is some cache system on your application or check if there is an **.htaccess** file with some browser cache rule.

Other thing that you can do, *just for development*, is to append a random version number to your js (or css) inclusion path: `myjsfile.js?v=1`

In php you can for example append the timestamp `echo "myjsfile.js?v=".time();`

The versione in url force the browser to download the file and not to use the browser cached version.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your wampp server and make sure that you are changing those files which you are currently accessing in your browser.